# Installing Selected Parcels time out in CDH5

Tags: timeout, cloudera-cdh

I'm trying to create a cluster after cloudera manager setup, and when `Installing Selected Parcels`, it stuck at `activating` giving the error `timed out` and the log gives the warning **Parcel not distributed but have active state ACTIVATING**.

please help, how to resolve this?

**Error log**

```
Unexpected exception during download
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/cloudera-manager/cm-5.5.3/lib/cmf/agent/src/cmf/downloader.py", line 276, in _download
    response = self.opener.fetch_url(request)
  File "/opt/cloudera-manager/cm-5.5.3/lib/cmf/agent/src/cmf/downloader.py", line 69, in fetch_url
    return urllib2.urlopen(request)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 127, in urlopen
    return _opener.open(url, data, timeout)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 404, in open
    response = self._open(req, data)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 422, in _open
    '_open', req)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 382, in _call_chain
    result = func(*args)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 1214, in http_open
    return self.do_open(httplib.HTTPConnection, req)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 1187, in do_open
    r = h.getresponse(buffering=True)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/httplib.py", line 1051, in getresponse
    response.begin()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/httplib.py", line 415, in begin
    version, status, reason = self._read_status()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/httplib.py", line 371, in _read_status
    line = self.fp.readline(_MAXLINE + 1)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/socket.py", line 476, in readline
    data = self._sock.recv(self._rbufsize)
timeout: timed out
```

Comment: Please check the cloudera manager agent log file and server log file to see if there is any error and post it in your quesiton.

Comment: @Lan, I've updated the error log